# Elastic Search Interval in Date Range Query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a requirement where my query should be like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "_source": [
    "dateCreated"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "range": {
          "date_published": {
            "from": "2019-01-01", //Fixed date
            "to": "--15 days from given 'from' date--" //Cannot find solution for this
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I could not find documentation for a simple requirement like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [date math](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math) you can achieve what you expect

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "_source": [
    "dateCreated"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "range": {
          "date_published": {
            "from": "2019-01-01",
            "to": "2019-01-01||+15d"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This works absolutely the way I wanted! :)